# How to connect to 10000 web servers with epoll and non blocking sockets?

Tags: c, client, epoll

I have a list of millions of IP addresses of web servers. I want to check they are up and running by doing a non blocking connect to each of the servers. I know from the reading I've done so far that it is theoretically possible to handle 10,000 concurrent connects to different servers using epoll. See the C10K problem for more information.

Can anyone provide a sample epoll based code that demonstrates how to connect to multiple servers on port 80 concurrently and remove finished jobs and add new ones to replace those that are finished?

Below I include code I have done so far. I have managed to do the asynchronous DNS part of the code that gets the IP addresses from a list of domain names.

```
#include <ares.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXWAITING 1000 /* Max. number of parallel DNS queries */
#define MAXTRIES      3 /* Max. number of tries per domain */
#define TIMEOUT    3000 /* Max. number of ms for first try */

#define SERVERS    "1.0.0.1,8.8.8.8" /* DNS server to use (Cloudflare & Google) */

static int nwaiting;

static void
state_cb(void *data, int s, int read, int write)
{
    //printf("Change state fd %d read:%d write:%d\n", s, read, write);
}

static void
callback(void *arg, int status, int timeouts, struct hostent *host)
{
    nwaiting--;

    if(!host || status != ARES_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lookup %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return;
    }

    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (host->h_addr_list[0] != NULL){
        inet_ntop(host->h_addrtype, host->h_addr_list[0], ip, sizeof(ip));
        printf("%s\n", ip);
    }
}

static void
wait_ares(ares_channel channel)
{
    struct timeval *tvp, tv;
    fd_set read_fds, write_fds;
    int nfds;

    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    nfds = ares_fds(channel, &read_fds, &write_fds);

    if (nfds > 0) {
        tvp = ares_timeout(channel, NULL, &tv);
        select(nfds, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, tvp);
        ares_process(channel, &read_fds, &write_fds);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * fp;
    char domain[128];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    ares_channel channel;
    int status, done = 0;
    int optmask;
    
    status = ares_library_init(ARES_LIB_INIT_ALL);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_library_init: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    struct ares_options options = {
        .timeout = TIMEOUT,     /* set first query timeout */
        .tries = MAXTRIES       /* set max. number of tries */
    };
    optmask = ARES_OPT_TIMEOUTMS | ARES_OPT_TRIES;

    status = ares_init_options(&channel, &options, optmask);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_init_options: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    status = ares_set_servers_csv(channel, SERVERS);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_set_servers_csv: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    do {
        if (nwaiting >= MAXWAITING || done) {
            do {
                wait_ares(channel);
            } while (nwaiting > MAXWAITING);
        }

        if (!done) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", domain) == 1) {
                ares_gethostbyname(channel, domain, AF_INET, callback, NULL);
                nwaiting++;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "done sending\n");
                done = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (nwaiting > 0);

    ares_destroy(channel);
    ares_library_cleanup();
    
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I have also managed to make a start on the epoll code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 80
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 64
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * fp;
    char servers[MAX_CONNECTIONS][128];
    int sockfd[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    struct sockaddr_in dest[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    char buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][MAXBUF];
    struct epoll_event events[MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS];
    int i, num_ready, connections = 0;
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /*---Open socket for streaming---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    { 
        if ( (sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }

    /*---Add socket to epoll---*/
    int epfd = epoll_create(1);
    struct epoll_event event[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        event[i].events = EPOLLIN; // Cann append "|EPOLLOUT" for write events as well
        event[i].data.fd = sockfd[i];
        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[i], &event[i]);
    }

    /*---Initialize server address/port struct---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[i]) == 1)
        {
            //printf("Adding ip %s\n", servers[i]);
            bzero(&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i]));
            dest[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
            dest[i].sin_port = htons(PORT);
            if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[i], &dest[i].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
                perror(servers[i]);
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    

    /*---Connect to server---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if ( connect(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i])) != 0 ) {
            if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                perror("Connect ");
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
    
        /*---Wait for socket connect to complete---*/
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, 1000/*timeout*/);
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                //printf("Socket %d connected\n", events[i].data.fd);
            }
        }

        /*---Wait for data---*/
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, 1000/*timeout*/);
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                //printf("Socket %d got some data\n", events[i].data.fd);
                connections++;
                printf("%d\r", connections);
                bzero(buffer[events[i].data.fd], MAXBUF);
                recv(sockfd[events[i].data.fd], buffer[events[i].data.fd], sizeof(buffer[i]), 0);
                //printf("Received: %s\n", buffer[events[i].data.fd]);
                close(sockfd[events[i].data.fd]);
                epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sockfd[events[i].data.fd], &event[events[i].data.fd]);
                if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
               {
                    if ( (sockfd[events[i].data.fd] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
                        perror("Socket");
                        exit(errno);
                    }
                    event[events[i].data.fd].events = EPOLLIN; // Cann append "|EPOLLOUT" for write events as well
                    event[events[i].data.fd].data.fd = sockfd[events[i].data.fd];
                    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[events[i].data.fd], &event[events[i].data.fd]);
                    //printf("Adding ip %s\n", servers[events[i].data.fd]);
                    bzero(&dest[events[i].data.fd], sizeof(dest[events[i].data.fd]));
                    dest[events[i].data.fd].sin_family = AF_INET;
                    dest[events[i].data.fd].sin_port = htons(PORT);
                    if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[events[i].data.fd], &dest[events[i].data.fd].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
                        printf("\n");
                        perror(servers[events[i].data.fd]);
                        exit(errno);
                    }
                    if ( connect(sockfd[events[i].data.fd], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[events[i].data.fd], sizeof(dest[events[i].data.fd])) != 0 ) {
                        if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                            perror("Connect again ");
                            exit(errno);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        close(sockfd[i]);
    }
    printf("Finished without errors\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs but gives the following error:

```
5Connect again : Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with eventually:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 80
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 1024
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 4096
#define TIMEOUT 10000
int sockfd[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct epoll_event event[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
int epfd;
struct sockaddr_in dest[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
char servers[MAX_CONNECTIONS][128];

void close_socket (int socket)
{
    close(sockfd[socket]);
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sockfd[socket], &event[socket]);
}

void make_socket_and_connect (int sock)
{
    if ( (sockfd[sock] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }
    event[sock].events = EPOLLIN; // Cann append "|EPOLLOUT" for write events as well
    event[sock].data.fd = sockfd[sock];
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[sock], &event[sock]);
    bzero(&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock]));
    dest[sock].sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest[sock].sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[sock], &dest[sock].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
        printf("\n");
        perror(servers[sock]);
        exit(errno);
    }
    if ( connect(sockfd[sock], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock])) != 0 ) {
        if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            printf("%s\n", servers[sock]);
            perror("Connect again ");
            //exit(errno);
        }
    }
}

int is_valid_ip(char *domain)
{
    if (!strcmp(domain, "255.255.255.255"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "192.168.1.0"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "127.0.0.0"))
        return 0;
        
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][MAXBUF];
    struct epoll_event events[MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS];
    int i, num_ready, connections = 0, done = 0;
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /*---Open socket for streaming---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    { 
        if ( (sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }

    /*---Add socket to epoll---*/
    epfd = epoll_create(1);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        event[i].events = EPOLLIN; // Cann append "|EPOLLOUT" for write events as well
        event[i].data.fd = sockfd[i];
        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[i], &event[i]);
    }

    /*---Initialize server address/port struct---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[i]) == 1)
        {
            //printf("Adding ip %s\n", servers[i]);
            bzero(&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i]));
            dest[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
            dest[i].sin_port = htons(PORT);
            if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[i], &dest[i].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
                perror(servers[i]);
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    

    /*---Connect to server---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if ( connect(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i])) != 0 ) {
            if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                perror("Connect ");
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
    
        /*---Wait for socket connect to complete---*/
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, TIMEOUT/*timeout*/);
        if (!num_ready) break;
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                connections++;
                printf("%d\r", connections);
                close_socket(events[i].data.fd);
                if (!done)
                {
get_domain_name:
                    if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
                    {
                        if (is_valid_ip(servers[events[i].data.fd]))
                            make_socket_and_connect(events[i].data.fd);
                        else
                            goto get_domain_name;                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        done = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        close(sockfd[i]);
    }
    printf("Finished without errors\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Try it. It's fast.